# Spring boot can not autowire repository bean for service test class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, autowired, spring-test

I am using a mock repository for my application.
Here is snippet how service looks:

```
@Service
public class WeatherStationService {

    @Autowired
    private WeatherStationRepositoryMock weatherRepository;
```

Here is repository code:

```
@Repository
public class WeatherStationRepositoryMock {

    @Getter
    private List<WeatherStation> stations = new ArrayList<>(
            Arrays.asList(
                    new WeatherStation("huston", "Huston station", RandomGenerator.getRandomGeoInformation()),
                    new WeatherStation("colorado", "Colorado station", RandomGenerator.getRandomGeoInformation())
            )
    );
```

It works fine when I am executing **main()** with `@SpringBootApplication`.

However, when I want to run test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = MockConfig.class)
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.BEFORE_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
public class WeatherStationServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    @Real
    private WeatherStationService weatherService;
```

It fails with the following stacktrace:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'edu.lelyak.repository.WeatherStationRepositoryMock' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

Here is MockConfig content:

```
@Configuration
public class MockConfig {
    //**************************** REAL BEANS ******************************
    @Bean
    @Real
    public WeatherStationService weatherServiceReal() {
        return  new WeatherStationService();
    }
```

`Real` is marker annotation for real instances:

```
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Qualifier
public @interface Real {
}
```

I can fix it with next initialization at service:

```
@Service
public class WeatherStationService {
    private WeatherStationRepositoryMock weatherRepository = new WeatherStationRepositoryMock();
```

It works fine.

Why does this happen?
***How to fix autowiring for my custom repository class?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@SpringBootApplication` implicitly defines `@ComponentScan`, which scans all subpackages for beans.
When you run a test using `MockConfig`'s, it doesn't scan for beans.

### Solution - use @ComponentScan OR define beans in MockConfig

**(1) Using @ComponentScan:**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan //Make sure MockConfig is below all beans to discover
public class MockConfig {
    @Bean
    @Real
    public WeatherStationService weatherServiceReal() {
        return  new WeatherStationService();
    }
}
```

**(2) or define required beans:**

```
@Configuration
public class MockConfig {
    @Bean
    @Real
    public WeatherStationService weatherServiceReal() {
        return  new WeatherStationService();
    }

    @Bean
    public WeatherStationRepositoryMock weatherStationRepository() {
        return new WeatherStationRepositoryMock()
    }
}
```

Comment: to my mind usage `@ComponentScan(basePackages = "edu.lelyak.repository")` is much more preferable here. Declaring new bean at `MockConfig` makes conflict which one should be used into real weather service class. I suppose that it is coz `MockConfig` is located under test folder -> as a result, we have 2 beans one with `@Repository` annotation, second from `MockConfig` class.